# Probability: Independent or Dependent for uniform random element sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

> **Question**:  You choose a uniformly random element, say $x$, from the set $\{1,2,3\}$ and you choose a uniformly random element, say $y$, from the same set $\{1,2,3\}$. ($x$ and $y$ are chosen independently of each other.) Define the events
>
> $A$ = “$x$ is odd",
>
> $B$ = “$x + y$ is odd".
>
> Are these independent or not? Show proof.

**Attempt**:

I got $\Pr(A) = 2/3$ (2 odd numbers $\{1,3\}$ to choose from $\{1,2,3\}$)

$\Pr(B)$ was confusing. I know that the addition of odd numbers is even. So, if $x = 1,3$ and $y=2$ will result in $x+y$ to be even. Then $\Pr($picking $2) = 1/3$ and $\Pr($picking $1,3) = 2/3$

$\Pr(B) = 1 – \left(\left(\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3}\right) + \left(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)$

$\Pr(B) = \frac{4}{9}$

$\Pr(A \cap B) = \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{4}{9}$

So they are independent? The answer is they are not independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(A) = \text{the probability that the first element chosen is odd} = 2/3$, for the reason you provided.

Next, to compute $P(B)$, note that we can only get an odd sum by having $x$ and $y$ of opposite parity. This can occur by setting $(x, y)$ equal to one of $(1, 2)$, $(3, 2)$, $(2, 1)$, $(2, 3)$. From listing all of the possible ways, we see there are exactly $4$ ways to obtain an odd sum out of $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ ways to choose $x$ and $y$. Thus, $P(B) = 4/6 = 2/3$.

$P(A \cap B)$ is the probability that the first element chosen is odd **and** the sum is odd. This can happen only if the second element chosen is even, meaning that the second element is $2$. There are only two ways to achieve this: $(x, y) = (1, 2)$ or $(x, y) = (3, 2)$. Once again, since there are $6$ total ways to choose $x$ and $y$, $P(A \cap B) = 2/6 = 1/3$.

To check for independence, we have to see whether the equation $P(A) \cdot P(B) = P(A \cap B)$ is satisfied. Since it is not satisfied $(2/3 \cdot 2/3 \neq 1/3$), we conclude that they are **not independent.**